Approximating the Prime Counting Function as $\pi(x) \approx \frac{x^2}{\ln\left(\Gamma(x+1)\right)}$
Approximating the Prime Counting Function as $\boxed{\pi(x) \approx \frac{x^2}{\ln\left(\Gamma(x+1)\right)}}$
Intro________________
In a unrelated topic I was viewing how the mechanical statistics Boltzmann's entropy approximation use the Stirling's approximation to match the Shannon entropy: there it is used the following,
$$N! \overset{\text{Stirling's}}{\approx}\sqrt{2\pi N}\left(\frac{N}{e}\right)^N \Rightarrow \ln(N!) \approx N\ln(N)-N+\frac12\ln(2\pi N)$$
But also there is the approximation (mildly worst):
$$\ln(N!) = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{N}\ln(k) \approx \int\limits_{1}^{N}\ln(u)\ du = N\ln(N)-N+1$$
So far I could find by myself, looks like Boltzmann used finally the approximation $$\ln(N!)\approx N\ln(N)$$
to match the average entropy per particle
$$\frac{S}{N} = \frac{\ln(W)}{N} = \frac{\ln(\frac{N!}{N_1!N_2!\cdots N_m!})}{N} \overset{\ln(N!)\approx N\ln(N)}{\approx}-\sum\limits_{k=1}^m \frac{N_k}{N}\ln\left(\frac{N_k}{N}\right) =-\sum\limits_{k=1}^m p_k\ln(p_k)$$
using that $\ln(N_k) = \ln\left(N_k \frac{N}{N}\right) = \ln(N)+\ln\left(\frac{N_k}{N}\right)$ and the fact that $\sum_{k=1}^m N_k = N$.
The success of his theory left these approximations in my handbook, even when plenty of terms were left outside the final formulas (without knowing myself why or what this have cost in terms of accuracy).
Main part__________________
Later I was seen a YouTube video about the Prime-counting function $\pi(x)$ where is explained it has the famous upper and lower bounds given by $\text{li}(x)$ the Logarithmic integral function and the function $f(x)=\frac{x}{\ln(x)}$, respectively.
So with the previous approximations in mind I wonder what would happen if I try to use the Stirling's approximation on the formula for $f(x)$:
$$f(x) = \frac{x}{\ln(x)}=\frac{x^2}{x\ln(x)}$$
which using the first approximation shown $x\ln(x) \approx \ln(x!)+x-\frac12\ln(2\pi x)$ I got the approximation:
$$f(x) = \frac{x^2}{x\ln(x)}\approx \frac{x^2}{\ln(x!)+x-\frac12\ln(2\pi x)} = g(x)$$
were it can be seen $g(x)$ behaves similar to $f(x)$. Since $f(x)$ its kind of a loose bound compared with $\text{li}(x)$, I remove terms from the denominator of $g(x)$ to see if it get closer to $\pi(x)$ (or equivalently, using the last approximation $\ln(x!)\approx x\ln(x)$), so I tried:
$$\pi(x) \approx \frac{x^2}{\ln(x!)} \approx \frac{x^2}{\ln\left(\Gamma(x+1)\right)} = h(x)$$
with $\Gamma(x)$ the Gamma function, and for my surprise it kind of fit $\pi(x)$ better than the bounds shown in Wikipedia: for $x>16$ the function $\text{li}(x)>h(x)>\frac{x}{\ln(x)}$ and actually for $16<x<5000$ the function $h(x)$ kind of surf in between the function $\pi(x)$, and for $x>5500$ it looks like works as a lower bound which is as tight as $\text{li}(x)$: all these just by a fast visual inspection, I am not tried to verify none of this observations rigorously.
I have zero knowledge about number theory, but since I don't found this approximation on the Wikipedia page for $\pi(x)$, I got to wonder if the approximation made any sense to begin with: if its wide known, please share its name and references (Googling for it didn't worked).
Here I left the plots I saw on Wolfram-Alpha:


Since $\log \Gamma(x+1) = x\log x - x + O(\log x)$,
\begin{align*}
\frac{x^2}{\log \Gamma(x+1)} &= \frac x{\log x - 1 + O(x^{-1}\log x)} \\
&= \frac x{\log x} \biggl(1 - \frac1{\log x} + O(x^{-1}) \biggr)^{-1} \\
&= \frac x{\log x} \biggl(1 + \frac1{\log x} + \frac1{\log^2 x} + \frac1{\log^3 x} + \cdots + O(x^{-1}) \biggr) \\
&= \frac x{\log x} + \frac x{\log^2 x} + \frac x{\log^3 x} + O\biggl( \frac x{\log^4 x} \biggr).
\end{align*}
However, we know from the prime number theorem that there exists a constant $c>0$ such that
$$
\pi(x) = \mathop{\rm li}(x) + O\bigl( e^{-c\sqrt{\log x}} \bigr) = \frac x{\log x} + \frac x{\log^2 x} + \frac{2x}{\log^3 x} + O\biggl( \frac x{\log^4 x} \biggr).
$$
Therefore
$$
\pi(x) - \frac{x^2}{\log \Gamma(x+1)} = \frac x{\log^3 x} + O\biggl( \frac x{\log^4 x} \biggr).
$$
While this is a slightly better approximation to $\pi(x)$ than $x/\log x$, whose difference with $\pi(x)$ is asymptotically $x/\log^2 x$, it's only about the same strength as the approxmation $x/(\log x-1)$, and nowhere near as good as li$(x)$ itself.
Even computations going up to one million show a marked difference. The first picture has the differences $\pi(x)-\mathop{\rm li}(x)$ in amber and $\pi(x)-x^2/\log \Gamma(x+1)$ in green; the second picture has the quotients $\pi(x)/\mathop{\rm li}(x)$ in amber and $\pi(x)/
\bigl(x^2/\log \Gamma(x+1)\bigr)$ in green.



Can you explain what's going on in the OP's plot then?

thanks for the detailed answer. There is a reason why it used as classic lower bound $\frac{x}{\ln(x)}$ instead of $\frac{x}{\ln(x)-1}$ you mentioned?

The OP's plot goes up to 1000. There are lots of functions we could fit to that data that are better than an asymptotically best bound.

Do you believe it is possible to relate the $\pi(x)$ function with Shannon or Boltzmann entropies through the approximations I used in the questions? Will it have any sense?

I doubt there's any useful connection with entropy. The mathematics is just about the functions themselves, and these particular functions are okay but not great at approximating $\pi(x)$.
